# How to resolve 'cannot find module 'serialport' using Node.js and Johnny-Five?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, leap-motion, johnny-five

**Main goal: using Johnny-five and node.js to run a script for my Arduino, using LeapMotion Controls**

I have a folder with my

1: 'robotarm.js' script

2.the Leapjs 'lib' folder

3. the 'node_modules' folder in leapjs which has underscore, glmatrix and ws.

I am have uploaded the Standard Firmata on the Arduino Board and I am trying to run my Script to start the program. However when I go to terminal, get inside my proj folder and type node robotarm.js, this is what happens:

```
 Kriss-MacBook-Pro:armproj Kris$ node robotarm.js

 module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'serialport'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Board.Serial.detect (/Users/Kris/node_modules/johnny-five/lib/board.js:69:7)
at new Board (/Users/Kris/node_modules/johnny-five/lib/board.js:299:23)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Kris/Desktop/armproj/robotarm.js:90:9)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Comment: Did you try `npm install -g serialport`

Comment: I wouldn't install `serialport` globally.  That's not what you want.  Delete your `node_modules` folder and try `npm install johnny-five` (or `npm install` if you have it in packages.json).  There was an inconsistency with the node-serialport binaries which required a build in some environments... and I am guessing that your build failed the last time you tried this.  Try installing J5 again.  LMK if you run into any further troubles.

Comment: @user2855405 Did you figure out your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Just `npm install` (not globally) did the trick for me. I didn't even have to delete my *node_module* folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
var board = new five.Board({ port: "COM3" });
```